# Iterate over JSON object keys and values with jq

Tags: json, jq

Here is `jq` getting field `a1`:

```
$ echo '{"a": {"a1": 1}, "b": {"a1": 2}}' | jq -r ".[] | .a1"
1
2
```

I'd like to get the keys `a` and `b` as well, and output a flat result, i.e.

```
$ echo '{"a": {"a1": 1}, "b": {"a1": 2}}' | jq -r "<magic here>"
a 1
b 2
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

I guess I found an answer:

```
$ echo '{"a": {"a1": 1}, "b": {"a1": 2}}' | \
   jq -r 'to_entries[] | [.key, .value.a1] | @tsv'
a   1
b   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative using [`keys` (or `keys_unsorted`)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#keys,keys_unsorted):

```bash
$ echo '{"a": {"a1": 1}, "b": {"a1": 2}}' |
   jq -r 'keys[] as $key | [$key, .[$key].a1] | @tsv'
a   1
b   2
```